# Insert multiple dates with DatePicker

Tags: yii2

I am working with `DatePicker` and the `multidate` option because I need to save several dates in a field of the DB table. The problem is that I do not know how to get the dates each one as an arrangement.

For example

In the field of the database the dates are saved as

- `2019-05-20`
- `2019-05-07`
- `2019-05-08`
- `2019-05-15`
- `2019-05-22`
- `2019-05-23`

How could I do that?

regards

Comment: you need to ask the question in english or go to spanish version of the site https://es.stackoverflow.com/ i have updated your question , about the question , what do you want to change the format for the date or something else please clearify

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: can you accept the answer please if it helped you

Comment: How can i do that? Of course the answer help me. Thanks

Comment: you can follow the instructions here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explode the dates and insert them one by one in the database. The `DatePicker`'s `multidate` option will provide you the dates as comma separated format like below

```
2019-05-20,2019-05-07,2019-05-08,2019-05-15
```

you can get the date from the post and then

```
$dates = Yii::$app->request->post('dates');
$myDates = explode(",",$dates);

foreach($myDates as $date){
    //insert your date into your relevant model
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for.